# Rearranging a factor inside a DATA set

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this data set called HAPPY, that has multiple different columns (AGE, MARITAL, DEGREE... and so on). I have these columns to be factor variables, and I am trying to rearrange the levels in the factor so they are in an order that makes sense. For example, I am trying to rearrange the MARITAL factors to c("Never Married" "Married "Separated", "Divorced", "Widowed"). I am supposed to use Dplyr to do this. Possibly using arrange, summarize, and group_by. 
This is what I did, but this is not close at all and I am struggling to figure this out:

`HAPPY %>%
  group_by(MARITAL) %>%
  summarize(n = n(), solo = mean(AGE)) %>%
  arrange(desc(solo))`

Thanks for your time!

https://xdaiisu.github.io/ds202materials/hwlabs/HAPPY.rds
here is the link to the data

Comment: We are not happy that we don't have the reproducible example of your HAPPY dataset.

Comment: how do I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: `dput(HAPPY)` :)

Comment: I added It in the link, let me know if this is ok, sorry its my first time here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your `rds` file, I noticed that the `MARITAL` column is in character, not factor. The way to convert it to factor is as follows with the `mutate` function. After that, you can re-arrange the row order using `arrange` with `desc` to make it in descending order.

```
library(dplyr)

HAPPY2 <- HAPPY %>%
  mutate(MARITAL = factor(MARITAL, 
                          levels = c("NEVER MARRIED", "MARRIED", "SEPARATED", "DIVORCED", "WIDOWED"))) %>%
  arrange(desc(MARITAL))
```

I am unclear why you want to use `summarize` and `group_by`. If you have a new question, please clarify.